# What does "One CPU is going to 'smoke' another CPU" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang, metaphors

I faced the following sentence:

> You really can’t say a 4.1GHz FX-8350 is going to **smoke** a 3.5GHz Core i7-3770K because in a hell of a lot of workloads the 3.5GHz Core i7 is going to dominate.

I can guess that 'smoke' is similar to the word 'win', but is it right?
What is the exact shade of meaning?

I appreciate getting the russian translation.

Comment: The Russian translation would be something like уничтожать, but not in the literal sense.

Comment: verb transitive Slang 5 b. To defeat decisively, as in a competition. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smoke

Comment: Ofk, I tried. But I wasn't satisfacted. It'd be great to find the precise meaning, the most accurate synonym. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have it right; "smoke" can be used to mean "win" (or maybe even, "win easily," or "win decisively").

When talking about lopsided contests, frequently-used slang verbs fall into a few different categories. For example, there's the word *beat*, along with its synonyms (such as *drub, thrash, whip,* and *trounce* – all of these words can be found in headlines, articles, and recaps of [sporting events](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nba/2015/11/08/heat-run-away-in-2nd-half-top-raptors-96-76/75434792/), [elections](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-35019111), and [business rivalries](http://www.ocregister.com/articles/angie-643557-art-chun.html)).

Another category would be metaphorical pressure from above, giving us words like *stomp* and *crush*.

Furthermore, when the contest involves blazing speed (such as races between sprinters or microprocessors), many of the verbs deal with fire, such as *smoke, burn,* or *torch*. Here are a few examples from recent news articles:

> the next-generation Samsung Exynos 7420 chip, which is said to power these newest flagship phones, [**burns the competition**](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2882495/report-galaxy-s6-benchmarks-offer-hint-of-powerful-next-generation-smartphone.html) with respect to 3D performance
>
> He [Jeff Gordon]  [**torched the field**](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/nascar/2015/11/21/jeff-gordon-how-four-championships-were-won/76071790/) with 13 wins, which nearly doubled the next-best driver
>
> "This is going to be a great game going against a team like that," Beckham said shortly after he **[burned the Dolphins](http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/football/giants/myers-perfect-panthers-facing-giants-history-article-1.2466406)** with a seven-catch, 166 yard, two-touchdown masterpiece

Comment: As mentioned below, "smoke" originally referred to killing someone by shooting them (with "smoke" referring to the residual smoke from guns at the time). I would suggest another category of these metaphorical verbs related to killing. Words such as "kill,  murder, choke, etc."

Comment: @JeremyFelix - I'll grant you that _kill_ is sometimes used, particularly in a lopsided contest. That said, _murder_, while not unheard of, is comparatively rare, I think, while _choke_ usually has another meaning altogether in the context of sports.

Answer (score 37):

To **smoke** someone originally meant (and still does mean) [to shoot them to death with a gun](https://books.google.com/books?id=ccHrlDVDdZUC&pg=PA132&dq=%22smoked%20him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJnpqY2N7JAhUCrD4KHdSHAssQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22smoked%20him%22&f=false). The reference was to the smoke coming from the weapon's muzzle.  This colorful term has come to mean "defeat soundly, trounce".

Comment: Wow, I never knew. My assumption was always the same as [@Jasper's](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/76029/11145), i.e. that it was to do with cars.

Comment: I think both meanings of "to smoke" could have arisen independently.

Comment: @user151841 they could have, but it doesn't seem likely to me. this meaning was in common use long before cars came about.

Comment: @sgroves It seems likely to me that they both developed independently. When people say that A "smoked" B in some sort of measurement, they mean that A vastly outperformed B, as a much faster car leaves competitors behind in its smoke. They don't mean that they killed or destroyed the competition.

Comment: @user151841: . You haven't provided any evidence for your claim that *to smoke*  (to outperform significantly) was not a figurative use which developed from the  meaning "to kill with a gun" but an independent development.  We often use words that mean to beat or thrash, or even to kill, in competition contexts.  **How did you guys do against Central High School in Friday's game? -- We killed them!**  You need to find some attestations.

Comment: It's my opinion, and this is a comment, so I don't need to provide evidence. In any case, there are metaphors for a sound defeat that originate from racing, such as "leave in the dust" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in-the-dust--leave-someone, "eat someone's dust" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eat_someone's_dust.

Comment: Dust is not smoke.  Don't know where you have gotten the idea that opinions, wherever they're presented, don't need to have some supporting argument or evidence.  That's a new one.

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smoke&defid=382039 Defintion #3 " To speed pass another driver, as if in a race."

Comment: @TRomano I get it from the definition, of course: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/opinion " 1.
a belief or judgment that rests on grounds insufficient to produce complete certainty. 2. a personal view, attitude, or appraisal." I would also like to point out that you have not, as of yet, provided evidence  or attestation that the "to kill" definition of "to smoke" is used as a metaphor for defeat in competition.

Comment: You're spinning your wheels.

Answer (score 17):

When I hear this expression, I think of two possible metaphors:

> Two cars are drag racing on a dirt road.  Carl's Camaro is much faster than Mary's Miata.  The Camaro quickly gets ahead of the Miata.  Both cars "kick up" dust.  Mary's Miata is literally in a dust cloud that Carl's Camaro "kicked up".  The Miata is figuratively "eating" the Camaro's dust.  In other words, the Camaro "dusts" the Miata.

The dust metaphor can be stretched a bit to "smoke":  Either the Camaro is burning a little oil, or Carl smokes cigarettes, or Carl spins his tires (causing the tires to give off smoke).  In other words, Carl's car "smokes" Mary's car.

> Two chips are racing to complete a task.  The i486 is much faster than the i286.  You could "overclock" the i286 to make it go faster, but the i286 might overheat.  If you overclocked the i286 enough to keep up, the i286 might literally burn up -- it would literally start to smoke.  Even if you did not try to destroy the i286, the huge difference in the test performance could be metaphorically described as "The i486 smoked the i286."

Answer (score 16):

The New Oxford American Dictionary says:

> 3 [ with obj. ] informal kill (someone) by shooting.
>
> • defeat overwhelmingly in a fight or contest.

That's a pretty exact definition; I have nothing to add to it.

Comment: I'll have to downvote, as this definition is not exhaustive enough to cover the example; one processor cannot 'shoot' another processor!

Comment: @cst1992, did you read the second part?  "Defeat overwhelmingly in a fight or contest"?  That is the *exact* definition; as for specifically what "contest" is being referred to, that could be explained separately but is dependent on the author's intent and isn't contained in the actual meaning of the word.

Comment: If you look at the start of the sentence "**You can't *really* say...**" it becomes clear the author is actually using the precise meaning above—in other words, the 4.1 GHz core is not going to defeat the other core *overwhelmingly* (despite the higher speed rating indicating the 4.1 GHz is superior by *some specific* measure ) because in many cases  the second mentioned core would compare favorably with the first.  Hence the defeat would not be *overwhelming* (assuming that the 4.1 GHz core would win at all which is not strictly specified in that sentence.)

Comment: From background information, the 4.1 GHz core is slower. I agree, that 'defeat in a contest(such as a benchmark) would fit, but then I suggest you put only that in your answer, and not the first one. It's confusing.

Comment: @cst1992: I think not only is this answer not in the least confusing - it's significantly *improved* by providing the first definition. Which is itself metaphorical, but since the second definition *arises* from the first, it's very helpful for learners to see the logical semantic progression from informal *kill* -> [by shooting, with associated gunsmoke] -> *defeat overwhelmingly*. Without that connection being made explicitly, an nns might feel like he's having to learn a completely different word, rather than a simple "extended meaning".

Comment: @FumbleFingers okay, if you say so

Answer (score 5):

In plain English the meaning is as follows:

"A 4.1GHz FX-8350 **is not necessarily going to make your computer run faster than** a 3.5GHz Core i7-3770K, because **in many real-life applications** the 3.5GHz Core i7 **is actually the faster processor."**

Comment: -1, I don't know that that's a particularly good phrasing, and it definitely does not explain the meaning of 'smoke'.

Comment: @DCShannon- You are correct. I have re-phrased the statement, which I hope is now more clear, while other posters have covered the etymology of the word "smoke." Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Smoking could mean better benchmarks (what you get when you run programs like Prime95, Furmark etc.) or better real-life experience (better stability, better single-core performance, etc.).