# Meaning of Smoke someone

Tags: meaning

I saw phrase from a X's song, where he says 'Purrp in that blunt, smoking suicide, bloody blunts'.T here's some explanation, **X is literally smoking Purp in his blunt, and smoking SpaceGhostPurp in this song, nice play on words**. A purp is some kind of weed, but what does it mean to smoke someone?

> and smoking SpaceGhostPurp in this song

Comment: Related ELL question: [Meaning of "one CPU will 'smoke' another"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76028/what-does-one-cpu-is-going-to-smoke-another-cpu-mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To smoke someone" means "to thoroughly beat someone in a contest" or "to kill someone".

I am not familiar with this song, but if the song is not about literally killing SpaceGhostPurp, then the phrase is probably being used figuratively to mean that the lyrical content particularly disparages SpaceGhostPurp, perhaps in the context of a rap battle or "beef".

The play on words does indeed derive from usual meaning of "to smoke purp", with "purp" being a type of cannabis.

Comment: To smoke someone can also mean to beat them in a contest/race by a large margin. [Jill smoked Dave in the bicycle race.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/smoke) I don’t think it’s exactly that sense in this context, but it’s worth mentioning.

Comment: @ColleenV, yeah I saw that meaning too, thank you!